# Array of Objects (JavaScript) merge and add properties with same key

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, dictionary, merge

I have an array of objects like so:

```
array = [{item_name: "necklace", quantity: "2"},
         {item_name: "necklace", quantity: "4"},
         {item_name: "bracelet", quantity: "5"}];
```

I would like to merge these objects in the array to end up with an array that looks like this:

```
array = [{item_name: "necklace", quantity: "6"},
         {item_name: "bracelet", quantity: "5"}];
```

I'm unsure how to begin to tackle this. I have tried concat and merge but these override the values. Do I need to map?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just simply loop over the array and push the values into a new array, checking first to see if the `item_name` is already in there.

An easier way to check if the object is already in the new array is to create an object with the `item_name` and its position in the new array.  Otherwise, you'd need to loop over the new array each time to check.

Try this:

```
function merge_data(array){
    var new_array = [],
        item_map = {};

    // Loop over the array
    array.forEach(function(v){
        var item = v.item_name;

        // The object is not already in the new array
        if(item_map[item] === undefined){
            // Push the object and save its index
            item_map[item] = new_array.length;
            // WARNING: This pushes a *reference* to `v` into the new array
            // which means when I update `new_array[pos]`, it'll also update
            // this object in the *original* array
            //new_array.push(v);

            new_array.push({
                item_name: item,
                quantity: v.quantity
            });
        }
        // The object is already in the new array
        else{
            // Get its index and update the quantity
            var pos = item_map[item],
                // quantity is a string, we need to make it into an int
                quantity = parseInt(new_array[pos].quantity, 10);

            new_array[pos].quantity = quantity + parseInt(v.quantity, 10);
        }
    });

    return new_array;
}

// Now `array` will have the merged data
array = merge_data(array);
console.log(array);
```

Comment: Don't forget that the quantities are strings and should be parsed as integers before adding. ie `parseInt(v.quantity, 10)`

Comment: @Hacknightly: I just added that after testing it quickly :-)